# drupal teaser starting position

Tags: drupal, teaser

Is there any way to control and manual specification for **start of teaser**?. for example:

```
This is my test paragraph to find the solution.i need to know how to control the starting position of the teaser............<--!break-->
```

i want to stat my teaser from 'i need' . is it possible ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'start of teaser' - can you explain a bit more (maybe a small example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way to get , except you can do by using split summary feature available in Drupal

or if you have little bit knowledge in PHP you can tune the function node_teaser() in node.module for your requirements

Answer (score 2):

I found myself unsatisfied with the way that Drupal handles teasers. My users found it very confusing to have to insert a special mark in the body (even though FCK Editor provides a button), and to use the checkbox to say whether the teaser should be included in the article.

My solution was to add a new (CCK) field that contains the teaser, and use the hook_nodeapi call to copy my CCK teaser into the node's teaser field when an article node is loaded. This makes sure that my teaser shows up everywhere the Drupal teaser is expected.